# Command and following content on the same page

Tags: samepage

I have a few commands which must be on the same page as following content. My LaTeX code is generated so I can't fix each problem manually.

Imagine situation with this code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\heading}{
    \noindent \textbf{heading}\\
}

\begin{document}

    %% ONLY FOR EXAMPLE 
    some text
    \vspace{185mm}



    \heading

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

which results to this output

[image]

How can I ensure that the heading will be always on the same page as following content? Thanks

Comment: Well, there are other ways to produce a heading. However, you could use a `minipage` or an unnumbered `section` (i.e. `\section*{My heading}`). But who/what generates this LaTeX code?

Comment: your heading code will generate underfull box warnings because of the misused `\\ `  If you want to keep _all_ the following para togetherput  all the text in a `\noindent\begin{minipage{\textwidth}...\end{minipage}` will keep it together, if you just want the heading to stay with the first few lines, but allow page breaking just use a proper heading command such as `\section*{heading}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `needspace` package is useful here. `\needspace{1in}\section{}` will only put the section header on the page if an inch is left on the page. Otherwise, it will move it to the next page.

Note I modified the OP's `\heading` macro to use `\section*` with an argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand{\heading}[1]{
  \needspace{1in}\section*{#1}
}

\begin{document}

    %% ONLY FOR EXAMPLE 
    some text
    \vspace{185mm}


    \heading{Heading}

    \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]